# story detail in reddit android app

Tags: android, android-layout

How would one implement a view like the story detail page in the Reddit Android app?

The header and the comments list move when scrolling down, and the upvote / comment / share toolbar part of the header sticks to the top (or the bottom of the screen).[image]

Comment: use CoordinatorLayout for this and you can achieve this thing